# solr 4 - migrating from single instance to cluster

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is it possible to migrate an existing Solr installation (v 4.6) with couple of cores (4-5) cores to a new cluster with all the data migrate?

I tried to find such an answer without any luck.
I guess I can setup a new cluster and "import" the data to it, but I prefer to skip this kind of headache.

Comment: What kind of cluster are you trying to set up? If you just want Replication and no Sharding, you can copy the data folder and set up zookeeper to get SolrCloud going. But if you want Sharding enabled, you cannot do it simply by migrating data - you might have to rebuild the index.

Comment: will rebuilding require me to delete all docs and insert them all over again? (sounds like pretty painful migration)

Comment: Yes; rebuilding means deleting all the docs and indexing them again.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set up replication without re-indexing the data but if you have to set up sharding in the new cluster, you have to re-index the data.